# cannot get the User Email from context in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an inbound policy that extracts the User Email from the context like this:

```
 <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="azure-func-staging" />

    <set-header name="customer-email" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.User.Email)</value>
    </set-header>

</inbound>
```

But no matter what I always get the following message:

```
set-header (0.788 ms)
{
"messages": [
    {
        "message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
        "expression": "context.User.Email",
        "details": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    },
    "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
]
```

}

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the user of the developer into the h***eader of the request***, you would add the following to the ***APIM policy***:

Here you have missed the ***return*** statement in policy code:

```
<set-header name="customer-email" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.User.Email)</value>
    </set-header>
```

Modify your above code bit like below and try:

```
<set-header name="user" exists-action="override">
    <value>@{var usr = context.User;
    return usr.Email;}</value>
</set-header>
```

For more details on examples of `context.user`, refer [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#a-namepolicyexpressionsexamplesa-examples)

Comment: perfect, didn't know that! thank you!